# Why am I getting "Create View must be the only statement in the batch" in this specific View?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-view

I am using SQL Server and  I have the following T-SQL query which is supposed to create a view in my database.

```
USE [MyDatabase]

CREATE VIEW [Test1] 
AS
    WITH cte1 AS
    (
        SELECT * FROM [Table1]
    ),
    cte2 AS  
    (
         SELECT cte1.* 
         FROM [cte1]
         WHERE cte1.[Month] BETWEEN '2019-01-01' AND '2019-12-31'
    )
    SELECT * FROM [cte2]
```

I am getting an incorrect syntax error message from this query:

> Create View must be the only statement in the batch

I have been looking for the solution here: [How to create a view with a CTE?](http://www.sqlusa.com/bestpractices2005/viewwithcte/)

However, I can't figure out what's wrong with my T-SQL query!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put a `GO` on its own line, between the `USE [MyDatabase]` and the `CREATE`

Comment: @user3115933: or alternatively, remove the `USE MyDatabase` entirely and manually ensure you're in the right database before executing the script ... the `CREATE VIEW` just **has to be** the only statement in the batch - as the error clearly says...